# Trying to call the webpage but getting error while calling it

Tags: django

THis is the views.py and getting error when I try to call the sports named function

```
 def index(request):
        ob=Com1.objects.all()
        
        return render(request,'index.html',{'ob':ob})
    
 def sports(request,name):
        cat=Categ.objects.filter(name=name)
        com=Com1.objects.filter(categ_id=cat[0].id)
    
        return render(request,'sports.html',{'com':com})
```

This is the main URLs.

```
    urlpatterns = [
        path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
        path('index/',views.index,name='index'),
        path('sports/<str:name>',views.sports,name='sports'),
```

Am I missing something to place or declare in Sports.html

```
    <li><a href="{%url 'sports'%}">Sports</a></li>
```

Comment: Please incoude the *full* traceback, furthermore provide a more descriptive title.

Answer (score 1):

Your `sports` needs a value for the `name`:

```
<li><a href="{%url 'sports' value_for_name %}">Sports</a></li>
```

where *`name_for_value`* is thus an expression that will provide a value for the `<str:name>` URL parameter, otherwise this URL does not make much sense. def

If you want to link to the index view instead, you use:

```
<li><a href="{%url 'index' %}">Sports</a></li>
```

If you made use of a [**`ForeignKey`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey) from `Com1` to `Categ`, you can filter with:

```
def sports(request,name):
        com=Com1.objects.filter(categ___name=name)
        return render(request,'sports.html',{'com':com})
```

Comment: I tried with these 2 methods but still it shows page not found
{%for i in com%}
<li> <a href="/sports/{{i.name}}">{{i.name}}</a></li>
  <li> <a href="{%url 'sports' {{i.name}}%}">Sports</a></li>
 {%endfor%}

This is the models.py 
class Categ(models.Model):
 name=models.CharField(max_length=100)

 def __str__ (self):
  return self.name

class Subcateg(models.Model):
 name=models.CharField(max_length=100)

 def __str__ (self):
  return self.name

Comment: class Com1(models.Model):
 title=models.CharField(max_length=50)
 categ=models.ForeignKey(Categ,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
 subcateg=models.ForeignKey(Subcateg,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
 Img=models.ImageField(upload_to='media')
 desc=models.TextField()

 def __str__(self):
  return self.title

Comment: @VinodRomina: it is `<a href="{%url 'sports' iname%}">`, so *without* the double brackets. In that case `i` should thus be a `Categ` object.